# Accurately Set the MySqlCommand Parameter Size

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, .net-4.0, mysql-connector

How can I accurately pass in the proper data size to the following line:

`objCmd.Parameters.Add(_PNs[i], _DTs[i]).Value = _PVs[i];`

It is passed an array of `ParameterNames, MySqlDbTypes`, however, I would like to be able to pass the in the data size as well... according to the MySqlDbType passed in.

I know text, varchar, etc... lengths will vary, but what about everything else?

p.s. C# using the latest version of MySQL, and the latest version of the MySql .Net COnnector

Here's what I have so far, but it does not seem to be nearly as accurate as I assume that it should be.

`objCmd.Parameters.Add(_PNs[i], _DTs[i], _EstimatedSize(_PVs[i])).Value = _PVs[i];`

```
// this method is pretty dumb but we want it to be fast.
internal int _EstimatedSize(object _val)
{
    if (_val == null || _val == DBNull.Value)
        return 4; // size of NULL
    if (_val is byte[])
        return (_val as byte[]).Length;
    if (_val is string)
        return (_val as string).Length * 4; // account for UTF-8
    if (_val is decimal || _val is float)
        return 64;
    if (_val is bool)
        return 1;
    return 32;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create two array sqlDType and sqlSize

```
SqlDbType[] sqlDType = new SqlDbType[] {SqlDbType.Int, SqlDbType.Float, SqlDbType.SmallInt, SqlDbType.TinyInt};
int[] sqlSize = new int[] { 4, 8, 2, 1 };
SqlDbType type = SqlDbType.Float;
int iIndex = Array.IndexOf(sqlDType, type);
int iSize = -1;
if (iIndex > -1)
    iSize = sqlSize[iIndex];
```

Comment: Should it work for MySql as well, as stated in the question? `p.s. C# using the latest version of MySQL, and the latest version of the MySql .Net COnnector`

Comment: It is a basic logic to get a value from one array by defining another value which is containing in another array but indexes are same. same as key value pair collection which is used in Dictionary Class. You can also use Dictionary Class instead of using two different array. In that case this code will works in all version.